# Read borders with javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

I have been struggling with myself on asking this here. Do any of you know a way to read borders with javascript?  What I want to do is read this image and get the content.

[image]

Comment: "read" how exactly, what would be the expected result from "reading" an image ?

Comment: More beneficial if you post your attempt(s) also.

Comment: i dont have any attemps yet. I been diggin around of how to do it and i havent found anything.

Comment: Look for _edge detection_. OpenCV may be a starting point, there are NodeJS bindings for it.